# filter Unix Timestamp from database

Tags: php, datetime, filter, utc

Suppose I want to see the last 24 hours data from my database which is saved as a Unix Timestamp.

So, the process will be:

1. Get current time.
2. Get last 24 hours time.

   ```
   Unix Timestamp ---
   current time --- 1439212332
   last 24 hours ---- 1439207714
   ```

I have tried in many different ways, but all my processes are wrong. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem ?

I am working on PHP and using a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mycolumn < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

This takes the date of 'now', subtracts one day from it and then converts it to a Unix timestamp to use on whichever column you're storing the value in.